# What is the meaning of "maintain the balance between good and evil"?

Tags: meaning

In Comedy movie "*Little Nicky (2000)*" film, In hell, Dad declares that he going to rule next 10,000 years
without giving throne to his three sons.

> I've decided that the ruler for the next 10,000 years is going to have
>   to be me. The important thing for the stability of our rule is to
>   **maintain the balance between good and evil**

Comment: The use of English seems entirely literal. What is causing a problem for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short it means "**to keep *(to)* the golden mean**"

To be *(maintain)* in mid-position between good and bad (evil).

Comment: Perthaps he is a follower of Zoroaster?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I doubt it. But I like the way you spelled "**perhaps**" with the "**t**" in the middle - "**perthaps**". The word thus is harmonious with "**Persia**" exactly where *Zarathustra* was from.

Comment: I haven't seen the movie, but the setting, Hell, and the name, *Little Nicky*, suggests something devilish to me (cf. "Old Nick") and so I don't think we're talking about a person who wishes to find the golden mean in himself but to oppose the forces of Good.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo You may be well correct there. Neither have I watched the movie but my assumption was based only on what context was given and other than that I'm out of ideas!